# Switching between Window Forms does not seem to work

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

Hey there StackOverflow community!

So I've been working on an application that checks if the user has entered valid credentials in a `Login()` form, then it switches over to an `Intro_Sequence()` form (where a .mp4 file is played in fullscreen mode) as a sort of aesthetic addition to the app. So far so good, no problems whatsoever.

The problem comes right after the Intro ends, where supposedly the application should switch over to a third form, called `Main()`.

I have implemented a check whenever Windows Media Player (aka `axWMPLib`) changes its `PlayState` to see whether it has finished the playback.

If it has, then the `Hide()` event is called to conceal the current Form's window, then `main.ShowDialog()` should open the third form.

Afterwards, I call the `Close()` event to close the previous Form's window entirely.

Here is the code so far:

```
    public partial class Intro_Sequence : Form
    {
        public static string Username;
        public Intro_Sequence(string username)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Username = username;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            TopMost = true;
            intro.uiMode = "none";
            intro.URL = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Intro.mp4";
            intro.enableContextMenu = false;
            DisableMouseClicks();
        }
        private void DisableMouseClicks()
        {
            if (this.Filter == null)
            {
                this.Filter = new MouseClickMessageFilter();
                Application.AddMessageFilter(this.Filter);
            }
        }

        private MouseClickMessageFilter Filter;

        private const int LButtonDown = 0x201;
        private const int LButtonUp = 0x202;
        private const int LButtonDoubleClick = 0x203;

        public class MouseClickMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
        {

            public bool PreFilterMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                switch (m.Msg)
                {
                    case LButtonDown:
                    case LButtonUp:
                    case LButtonDoubleClick:
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void Intro_Sequence_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void intro_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
        {
            if(intro.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
            {
                Main main = new Main(Username);
                this.Hide();
                main.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have also added a filter to block clicks during playback, so as not to allow the user to pause it.

However, when I execute this code, it works perfectly fine until it finishes the video and then closes abruptly.

I tried putting breakpoints and everything seems to be fine.

It does call everything I tell it to call, yet the form doesn't even appear.

I have also tried several other alternatives, like not closing the Form at all, calling `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()` and even not Hiding it at all.

It is as if it either freezes there or closes instantly without any sign of the Main form showing.

I also tried calling the `Main()` form from the `Login()` and it works perfectly from there.

I really don't know what is going on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `this.Close();` comment out this line and see.

Comment: I don't know anything about the `PlayStateChange` event, but...  I'd be tempted to put a trace line in at the beginning of the event handler (using `Debug.WriteLine`) that prints out the `intro.playState` value, some thread information (just the thread number should do), things like that.  See what's going on

Comment: @RaoHammas Already tried, it crashes. Final line in output: "The program [11480] DoublePulsar v3.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

Comment: @Flydog57 Start = wmppsReady Transition = wmppsTransitioning Playback = wmppsPlaying and finally wmppsMediaEnded

Comment: How do you start this all up?  An out-of-the-box WinForms app includes this in program.cs: `Application.Run(new Form1());` When `Form1` closes, the program quits.  You can also use an `ApplicationContext` to manage multiple forms.  What does yours look like?

Comment: Run `Main` as the starting Form. Hide it, then - when the playback is terminated - show it  and close the rest. Don't block an event handler as `PlayStateChange` with a dialog in any case. -- Note that if you change `ShowInTaskbar` property when a Form handle has already been created, the handle needs to be recreated. It may have consequences (if you have code that acts on the handle creation). Or not, if no code (at least, your code) acts on that.

Comment: In `Login`, are you displaying `Intro_Sequence` with `ShowDialog()`?  If so, `this.Hide()` in `Intro_Sequence` will cause `ShowDialog()` to return execution to `Login`.  Do you have code in `Login` afterwards that possibly shuts down the application?

Comment: I agree that you need to rethink the program flow; I'd personally go with the ApplicationContext approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

There are three forms.  There's a *Login* form (in this case, it's just an empty form - you close it by clicking on the red X).  It is popped up modally from within the *Main* form (while the main form is hidden).

There's a *Splash* screen on which your video is to play.  I fake out the video by using `await Task.Delay(4000);` to get a pause.  After the 4 second delay, I raise an event (equivalent to your media player event).  What I do is show this modally from the main form.  I put the event handler in this form; when the event is raised, I close the splash screen modal.  The entire (non-designer) code for that form looks like (and, since there are no controls on this form, the designer code is pretty lean):

```
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
{
    public event EventHandler SplashFinished;
    public SplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SplashFinished += SplashScreen_SplashFinished;
    }

    private async void SplashScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(4000);
        SplashFinished?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    private void SplashScreen_SplashFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Then there's the *Main* form.  It gets fired up in the normal way from `Program.cs`:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

The only thing that I added to that form (from the out-of-the-box code) is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    var login = new LoginForm();
    //should really check this, but for now
    login.ShowDialog(this);
    var splash = new SplashScreen();
    splash.ShowDialog(this);
    this.Show();
}
```

So, when the app starts, the user is shown the login form (the main form is hidden).  He does what is needed to do (and the result is checked in the main form's `Form1_Load` handler.

If everything is cool, a new `SplashScreen` form is created and shown modally.  When it pops up, the video starts (in this case, the video is simply an asynchronous timer).  When the video ends, the ***SplashScreen handles the finished*** event, and uses it to close itself.

Once control returns to the main form, it displays itself.

Comment: This is indeed a viable solution, the only problem with this is that in order for the Main form to show, you need to obtain a field called "Username" `Main(string username)` and the way to do this is through the login Form. So starting up with main is not an option, as I don't have that username. However, this is a logically correct solution, therefore I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Start Main up with no username. The first thing the form does is pop up up the login form, so it can pull the information from there. If there is a problem with the login, you can do something in Form Load. Is there a reason you need the username before form Load (for example, you need to change the window creation parameters  (styles,  etc)?