# How can I show the window in WPF without lost controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a program when I log in, I have to wait for loading database from server. So I created a "Loading..." window. After loading the database, this will automatically close the "Loading" window, the "Login" window and open the MainWindow.xaml.
But myprogram have a problem: when I use waitForm.show() in Login.xaml.cs, it runs good, but the controls on "Waiting" window like progressbar, textblock, it doesn't display.If I use waitForm.showdialog(), it will display progressbar and textblock control. But it won't automatically close. So my Mainwindow.xaml not open.
Is it possible to use show() but show the controls?
Sorry about my bad English. Thank you.

Waiting.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TMO.Waiting"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TMO"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Waiting" Height="100" Width="300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None">    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ProgressBar Margin="10,20,10,5" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Name="pbStatus" IsIndeterminate="True" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,5" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" >Loading...</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Waiting.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TMO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Waiting.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Waiting : Window
    {
        public static MessageBoxResult result;
        public Waiting()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Waiting(Window parent1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();             

        }
        public void CloseWaiting()
        {
            DialogResult = true;
            this.Close();           
        }       
    }
}
```

WaitFunc.cs

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
namespace TMO
{
    public class WaitFunc
    {
        Waiting wait;
        Thread loadthread;
        public void show()
        {
            loadthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadingProcess));
            loadthread.Start();
        }
        public void show(Window parent)
        {
            loadthread=new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(LoadingProcess));
            loadthread.Start(parent);
        }
        public void Close()
        {
            if(wait!=null)
            {
                wait.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(wait.CloseWaiting));
                wait=null;
                loadthread=null;    
            }
        }
        public void LoadingProcess()
        {
            wait=new Waiting();
            wait.ShowDialog();
        }
        public void LoadingProcess(object parent)
        {
            Window parent1 = parent as Window;
            wait=new Waiting(parent1);
            wait.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Login.xaml.cs

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Waiting waitForm = new Waiting();
    waitForm.Show();      //If I use waitForm.showdialog() it will display all control
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow(txtUserName.Text);              
    this.Hide();   
    waitForm.Close();
    main.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Threads and windows really don't mix well.  I'm not a WPF person (so I can't tell you the right way to do this, but that extra thread is likely the problem.  You need to figure out how to open the "waiting" window, and when it closes send a message to the other window to show itself.  Also, learn about `await Task.Delay`; using `Thread.Sleep` in a UI is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you. This program is written in WinForms, but now I change it to WPF. I am new in WPF so I have a lot of problem with WPF.

Comment: For Winforms, take a look at my answer to this question.  You may be able to adapt it to WPF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936319/switching-between-window-forms-does-not-seem-to-work/62944707#62944707

Comment: @FlyDog57 is correct regarding Threads and Windows. Behind the scenes, what you’ve unintentionally done here is create a form on one thread, but initialize the components on a different thread. Windows in C# are always created on the initial app thread regardless of where they are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You should manage all windows of the application launch sequence from the entry point of your application. Therefore, I recommend to move the logic to start the `MainWindow` from the *Login.xaml.cs* to the *App.xaml.cs*.

Furthermore, to create a UI thread that can show controls and allows input handling you must explicitly configure the thread to be a STA thread and additionally start the `Dispatcher` message loop.

Note, if you use async APIs and background threads when necessary (use `Task.Run` and not `Thread`), then you don't need an extra UI thread only to show the splash screen.

You should add a `LoginSuccessful` and a `LoginFailed` event to the `LoginWindow`.

Your flow could be implemented like this:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application Startup="App_OnStartup" />
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
  private Window SplashScreen { get; set; }

  private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

    var loginScreen = new LoginWindow();
    loginScreen.LoginSuccessful += RunApplication_OnLoginSuccessful;
    loginScreen.LoginFailed += ShutdownApplication_OnLoginFailed;
    loginScreen.Show();
  }

  private void RunApplication_OnLoginSuccessful(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var newUiThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowSplashScreen))
    {
      ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA,
      IsBackground = false,
    };

    newUiThread.Start();

    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.Loaded += CloseSplashScreen_OnMainWindowLoaded;
    mainWindow.Closed += ShutdownApplication_OnMainWindowClosed;

    // TODO::Initialize application

    mainWindow.Show();
  }  

  private void ShowSplashScreen()
  {
    this.SplashScreen = new Window() { Content = "SplashScreen" };
    this.SplashScreen.Show();

    // Start event queue
    Dispatcher.Run();
  }  

  private void CloseSplashScreen_OnMainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.SplashScreen.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
      this.SplashScreen.Close();
      this.SplashScreen.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    });
  }  

  private void ShutdownApplication_OnMainWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) => Shutdown();

  private void ShutdownApplication_OnLoginFailed(object sender, EventArgs e) => Shutdown();
```