# Can you safely run multiple message pumps on multiple threads in a standard c# .net winforms app

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I've read a lot of things vaguely warning against multithreading your Winforms ui in any way.
I have a legacy application that is standard STAthread Main() with the one call to Application.Run(mainform), so there is just 'one ui thread'. With any modifications to ui by other threads done via Invokes.

The app takes a while to load, and so I want to show a splash screen. I want this screen to be responsive, have a progress bar that updates etc, and maybe even a close button.  As mentioned this is a complex legacy application so the ideal solution of 'just do all your processing on a background worker thread' is not an option.

My plan is to create a thread, set it to STA, and inside that thread, it will call Application.Run(splashScreenForm). Obviously any communication between the main thread (thats doing the loading) and this splash screen thread will be managed appropriately. The main thread will call Application.Run(mainform) before the splash screen closes, so we will breifly have two message pumps going on different threads. Then the main thread will signal the splash screen thread to close the splash screen, which should in turn cause that thread's Application.Run to exit and the splash screen thread to terminate.

**My question is**: Is this safe? could there be any side effects of doing this? (for example, does windows try and send messages to an application that aren't for a specific window, and hence it wouldn't know which thread/message pump to send it to?)

I know a prominent library (DevExpress) does somehow allow you to have a splash screen that is managed by another thread, so I assume there must be some 'proper' way to do this.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's doable, but however told me that said you'd need a death wish to do it; it requires precise thread choreography. Why not do it all on one thread. Have your main window "open" unseen. Before it starts its lengthy initialization, have it bring up to splash screen. Then when it's finished the init work, it closes the splash screen. `async` and `await` make this much easier to do.

Comment: The inbuilt splash screen functionality in VB.NET WinForms apps creates and displays the splash screen on a secondary thread, so Microsoft obviously consider it safe to do what you want to do. [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?628109-Multi-threaded-Splash-Screen-in-WinForms)'s one I prepared earlier. I haven't touched it in over a decade but it seemed to work fine when I created it.

Comment: One point to note with my example is that the startup form is created first, then the splash screen is created and displayed, then the startup form is displayed. This assumes that the creation of the startup form is relatively quick and the long-running work is done on the `Load` event. You could rejig things if the creation was slow but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Here's an example of doing it all on one thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944707/4739488

Comment: @Flydog57, your example is fine if the splash screen is purely informative but if it is being used for the original purpose splash screens were created for, i.e. to give the user something to look at while the application does the work to prepare the main form, then it's of less value. Because you call `ShowDialog` on the splash screen form in the `Load` event handler of the main form, the main form can't do anything while it's displayed. That's why using multiple threads can be beneficial: it allows the main form to do work while the splash screen is displayed.

Comment: AFAIK it is safe, as long as you use `STAThread` and you do not under any circumstances attempt to do anything UI related from the wrong thread for that UI.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was talking about in the comments - getting a functional main form and a functional splash screen running on one thread.  I actually dispatch some initialization work to a background thread (calling back to the main windows to mimic doing something like fetching a bunch of data from somewhere).

First start a new WinForms project.  Rename Form1 to `MainForm` (to keep things straight).  Then create a secondary form, and name it `SplashScreen`.  Double click each form to create a `[FormName]_Load` handler.

Drop a label control on each form.  Name the one on the splash screen `CounterLabel` and on the MainForm, `StatusLabel`.  Format them both nicely

**On the SplashScreen:**

Add a private boolean:

```
private bool _cancelled = false;
```

Add a FormClosing event handler:

```
private void SplashScreen_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    _cancelled = true;
}
```

and use this code for the `SplashScreen_Load` handler:

```
private async void SplashScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 1;
    while (!_cancelled)
    {
        CounterLabel.Text = counter.ToString();
        counter++;
        await Task.Delay(400);
    }
}
```

The result of this is that while the form is open, there will be a label on it that slowly counts up from 1 to whatever (forever), until the form closes.  In real life, you could do something more interesting.

**Create a class**, name it `BackgroundThead`.  It has one method:

```
public class BackgroundThead
{
    public async Task DoUpdateWork(MainForm form)
    {
        var bunchOfNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
        foreach(var num in bunchOfNumbers)
        {
            form.UpdateForm(num);
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

What it does is that every 100 ms, it calls back into the main form, passing integers the integers from 1 to 100, one at a time (notice, it doesn't care what thread it's on).

**Finally, for the Main Form:**

Add an `UpdateForm` method.  It's going to use `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` in the normal fashion to allow the method to be called from any thread:

```
public void UpdateForm (int value)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(UpdateForm, value);
        return;
    }
    StatusLabel.Text = $"Status: {value}";
}
```

It will update the label on the main form whenever it's called. *(remember, it gets called from a background thread)*

And, in the main form's Load event handler, do this:

```
private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
    splashScreen.Show(this);
    var backgroundThreadWorker = new BackgroundThead();
    await Task.Run(() => backgroundThreadWorker.DoUpdateWork(this));
    splashScreen.Close();
}
```

When the form loads, it will bring up the splash screen form *non-modally*.  Once that form is up, it will create a `BackgroundThread` instance and call `DoUpdateWork` on it asynchronously, await-ing until it's finished.  Once it's finished, it will close the splash screen.

That `DoUpdateWork` call mimics any initialization work that the main form may need to do.

Press `F5`, pull the two windows apart so that you can see them both and watch what happens.  The main form pops up.  The splash screen shows in front of it.  The main form counts quickly to 100.  The splash screen counts more slowly to about 25 or 26.  When the main form hits 100, it closes the splash screen.

Both forms are running on the same thread.  An initialization work it done on a separate thread, calling back into the main form to update it as needed (but having the form marshal the call onto the main thread).